# what is x-Application-Context header?

Tags: security, web, spring-boot, owasp

What is this response header (x-Application-Context)  stands for? is it specific to Spring framework?

what does the below header means?

```
X-Application-Context   airtel-project-service:aws:27094
```

does it reveals any senstive information like hostname or port number?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Spring Boot [ApplicationContextHeaderFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/filter/ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.html) does add this header.
Class description:

> OncePerRequestFilter to add a X-Application-Context header that contains the ApplicationContext ID.

[`AppliationContext ID`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html?is-external=true#getId--) is a name for the deployed application that this context belongs to.

You can change the default behavior by setting `management.add-application-context-header` property to `false`.

```
management.add-application-context-header=true # Add the "X-Application-Context" HTTP header in each response.
```

[Spring Boot resolved issue 1308](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1308).

Comment: On my config, springboot does not recognize a comment that is on the same line than a property definition. I had to move it above.