# Who uses the X-Application-Context header?

Tags: spring-boot, header

In Spring Boot the `X-Application-Context` header is set by the `ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.class`.

My question: What is the reason for this header? Is it used internally? Can it be changed without any sideeffect/impact?

The documentation I found is unclear.

### Update 1

Base on: [Stack Overflow: what is x-Application-Context header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379550/what-is-x-application-context-header)

### Update 2

For me the internal usage is still unclear and I will use a custom header instead. But I am still interested in the internal usage.

Answer (score 2):

`X-Application-Context` It is a name for the deployed application that this context belongs to. Context in this case a [`Spring ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html?is-external=true#getId--).

The header itself can be used for debugging purpose. But it also can repsent a possible server port leaking risk. In production it is usually behind some security proxy and it doen't get exposed.

The header exposure can be stopped by setting `management.add-application-context-header: false`.

Comment: So the header is not internally used. It is just there for debugging/testing/... right?

Comment: I haven't heard about it.